# Pass Accessibility Props to Material UI Button

Tags: reactjs, button, material-design, material-ui, accessibility

I want to add accessibility features to the [Material UI Button](https://material-ui.com/api/button/).

I expect to use this custom button as follows:

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

function AccessibleButton(props) {
  const { accessKey, ariaLabel, isDisabled, label, onClick, tabIndex, variant, size} = props;
  return (
    <Button
      accesskey={accessKey}
      aria-label={ariaLabel}
      disabled={isDisabled}
      className={componentCls}
      onClick={onClick}
      tabindex={tabIndex}
      variant={variant}
      size={size}
    >
      {label}
    </Button>
  );
};
```

Aria labels are available for [inputs](https://material-ui.com/components/checkboxes/#accessibility), but don't seem to be for buttons. How do I pass the additional props (accessKey, ariaLabel) into the Material UI Button. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work since most of our components forward their excess props. On the corresponding api pages (here https://material-ui.com/api/button/) you will find a table with the apparent props. Below that is a note that tells you what happens with excess props.

It's a bit iffy to navigate (we're working on it) but in the end you'll see that excess props are forwarded to the native element. So `<Button aria-label="ariaLabel" />` will render a `<button aria-label="ariaLabel" />`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work.

I have created sandbox where you can inspect the button and see the button will have aria-label and accesskey attribute.

```
  <Button
    aria-label="This is aria label"
    accessKey="Key"
    variant="contained"
    color="primary"
  >
    I'm a button
  </Button>
```

Try inspecting button in below sandbox.

[image: Edit Material-ui]